# Pandas string search in list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

How can I search for the string `'data1'` in the following Pandas dataframe?

This is where the string can be found:

```
df.test[0][0]['term']
'data1'
```

Further information regarding dataframe structure:

```
df.test[0]

[{'term': 'data1', 'a': "foo", 'b': "bar"},
 {'term': 'data2' ,'a': "foo", 'b': "bar"}]

type(df.test)
pandas.core.series.Series

type(df.test[0])
list

type(df.test[0][0])
dict
```

**What have I tried?**

I appreciate that something like `df.test.str.contains('Data1')` is required but I'm not sure how to do this with the nested list/dict data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is convert to string, so test by string represenatation of list of dicts:

```
df.test.astype(str).str.contains('data1')
```

If need test by `term` key:

```
df['test'].apply(lambda x: any(y.get('term') == 'data1' for y in x))
```

Or by all values of dicts:

```
df['test'].apply(lambda x: any('data1' in y.values() for y in x))
```

**Sample**:

```
a = [{'term': 'data1', 'a': "foo", 'b': "bar"},
 {'term': 'data2' ,'a': "foo", 'b': "bar"}]
b = [{'term': 'data4', 'a': "foo", 'b': "bar"},
 {'term': 'data2' ,'a': "foo", 'b': "bar"}]
df = pd.DataFrame({"test": [a, b]})
print (df)
                                                test
0  [{'term': 'data1', 'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}, {'...
1  [{'term': 'data4', 'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}, {'...

print (df.test.astype(str).str.contains('data1'))
0     True
1    False
Name: test, dtype: bool

print (df['test'].apply(lambda x: any(y.get('term') == 'data1' for y in x)))
0     True
1    False
Name: test, dtype: bool

print (df['test'].apply(lambda x: any('data1' in y.values() for y in x)))
0     True
1    False
Name: test, dtype: bool
```